# handle manual invoice payments and online store payments via Paypal and IPN

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

My situation is the next:
I have Magento store that processes payment with Paypal (Paypal standard). The store uses IPN to confirm the payment and has special URL for IPN

I also sometimes issue invoices through Paypal to some customers manually for something that is not related with what I sell in Magento store. Kind of pretty separate line of business.

The problem is that Paypal is trying to send IPNs for the payment of these manually issued invoicse to my Magento store. The store doesn't answer because can't recognise the payment that it isn't responsible for and I am getting warning from Paypal about IPN error.

What is the best practice to handle this problem?